# Eigenvalue as coefficient in time-dependent PDE in COMSOL

Tags: scientific-computing, comsol

I'm solving an eigenvalue problem in COMSOL. And after this, I'd like to use the eigenvalue as a coefficient in different physics. Thus, does anybody know what name stands for eigenvalue in Coefficient Form PDE in an eigenvalue study COMSOL? I expected something like u.ev but there is no such an attribute. Equation view shows only domflux.ux, domflux.uy, domflux.uz.

Also I've found c.omega. Is it the same as an eigenvalue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of PDE, according to COMSOL Referecnce Manual:

> After solving an eigenvalue problem, the eigenvalue is always
>   available for postprocessing under the variable name *lambda*,
>   independently of whether the problem has been specified using the *ea*
>   and *d* a coefficients or using the variable *lambda*.